# Azure yaml NodeTool step does not install specific version for pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the [NodeTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/node-tool-v0?view=azure-pipelines) and [UseNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-node-v1?view=azure-pipelines) steps in my Azure yaml pipeline:

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'set node v16.19.0'
    inputs:
      versionSource: 'spec'
      versionSpec: '16.19.0'
  
  - task: UseNode@1
    displayName: 'use node v16.19.0'
    inputs:
      version: '16.19.0'

  - script: |
      sudo node -v
    displayName: 'Node Version'
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

  - script: |
      sudo npm run build -- --mode $(NPM_BUILD_MODE)
    displayName: 'Building SPA with NPM'
```

But when I run the pipe, the `Node Version` step outputs:

```
v18.14.1
```

And the end of the `Building SPA with NPM` step outputs:

```
Node.js v18.14.1
```

How can I force the build machine to use my desired Node version, if the `NodeTool` does not do this?

Answer (score 1):

I Got the same issue with [NodeTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/node-tool-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in my Azure pipeline:

**Brief Answer**

This is because the script has sudo node -v instead of node -v, sudo node -v picks the node version from the root user.

Basically the NodeTool Downloads and updates the node path for the current User but still leaves the Root user's node as default version or the Latest LTS version.

**Detailed Answer**

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'set node v16.19.0'
    inputs:
      versionSource: 'spec'
      versionSpec: '16.19.0'
  
  - task: UseNode@1
    displayName: 'use node v16.19.0'
    inputs:
      version: '16.19.0'

  - script: |
      node -v # this needs to be changed from sudo node -v to node -v
    displayName: 'Node Version'
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

  - script: |
      npm run build -- --mode $(NPM_BUILD_MODE) 
    displayName: 'Building SPA with NPM'
```

Changing the following

```
  - script: |
      sudo node -v # this needs to be changed from sudo node -v to node -v
    displayName: 'Node Version'
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

to:

```
  - script: |
      node -v
    displayName: 'Node Version'
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

This is because it picks the latest node version for the root user (sudo)